# Why does "echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup" change Enabled to Disabled

Tags: acpi, proc

I have a very basic question.  I understand what `echo` does, and how it directs a string to the file `/proc/acpi/wakeup`.

My question is what is actually happening when I direct the word `EHC1` to `/proc/acpi/wakeup`.  Why does it change the line under `Status` from `*enabled` to `*disabled` or vice versa?

Thank you!  Why doesn't it just append the word `EHC1` to the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the other files at `/proc/` the file `/proc/acpi/wakeup` is not a real file but an interface to some kernel functions.

If you write something into it, the value you wrote isn't stored in a file but a kernel functions is called and does something with the value.

If you read from it another kernel function is called that creates some output that appears as the content of that file.